# def and initializing. what is "obj"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand the second line of the code below because of "obj = nil" in the first line.Given that, the second line seems to me that "obj" always becomes nil, return false and params[:id].to_i would be put into id_num. Could you tell me why it is written like this?

☆application_controller

```
 def me? obj = nil
  id_num = obj !=nil ? obj.member_id : params[:id].to_i
  if session[:user_id] == id_num then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a method that has a parameter set to `nil` means that the parameter is **optional**.

```
def output_object_or_say_duck(obj=nil)
  if obj
     puts obj
  else
     puts 'Duck'
  end
end
```

A good example of optional parameters as a design pattern is when you want default behavior that can be customized if necessary. A web request is a good example.

```
def make_web_request(website, parameters={}) # parameters OR empty hash
    Net::HTTP.get("#{website}?#{ parameters.to_query }")
end
```

This line of code:

```
id_num = obj !=nil ? obj.member_id : params[:id].to_i
```

is a [ternary operator](http://invisibleblocks.com/2007/06/11/rubys-other-ternary-operator/) which says if the object exists, assign `id_num` to the `member_id` attribute of `obj`, otherwise use `param[:id].to_i` (`.to_i` converts to an integer).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand obj is a parameter. But still, I have no idea what "obj.member_id" means because it is used as if it was a instance(variable) although there is no definition about obj in my sample code on the textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The `obj = nil` in the first line simply indicates that the default value of the obj parameter is nil.  Meaning that if you don't call the method with any arguments, obj will be set to nil.  So the me? method can take 0 or 1 arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand obj is a parameter. But still, I have no idea what "obj.member_id" means because it is used as if it was an instance(variable) although there is no definition about obj in the sample code on my textbook.